# Trigonometry fraction integral?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Can anyone help me solve this problem using u substitution.

$$\int \frac{\sec(2x)\tan(2x)}{1+\sec(2x)}dx$$

How would I solve this problem what could I use as my $u$ substitution?

Comment: Try substituting for the denominator.

Comment: Yes I see it now I guess It is not too tough of a problem the trig functions intimidated me...

Comment: If I see all the trig functions with one argument, $(2x)$, and the differential with a different argument, $(x)$, the **first** thing I'd so is let $u=2x$.  This would remove one layer of obfuscation (the simplest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The derivative of secant is

$$\frac{d}{du} \sec u = \sec{u} \tan{u}$$

This suggests trying something like

$$u = 1 + \sec{2x}$$

Comment: Ok let me see if it works.

Comment: for my final answer I got $(1/2) ln(1+sec(2x)$

Comment: In answers to homework/tests, don't leave out the $+C$!

Answer (score 2):

Take $u=\sec(2x)$ then $du=2\sec(2x)\tan(2x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, you could also multiply through by cos²(2x). The integral has then the more "friendly" trig terms. The u-sub is then REALLY easy...